# Multiple image upload in Django using AJAX & jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, django

I want to implement dynamic multiple image upload for an application in Django. I got to know that Django doesn't have any in-built support for that and external libraries have to be used.

I followed the blog - https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/11/22/django-multiple-file-upload-using-ajax.html

But the result I'm getting is nowhere close to what is expected.

Starting with settings.py

```
import os
SETTINGS_DIR = os.path.dirname(__file__)
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.join(SETTINGS_DIR, os.pardir)
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.abspath(PROJECT_PATH)
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

models.py

```
class Images(models.Model):

    file = models.FileField(upload_to='profile_images')
    category = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False)
    time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.category
```

forms.py

```
class ImagesForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Images
        fields = ['file',]
```

upload.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Upload</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="category_form" method="post" action="/rango/upload/" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{% csrf_token %}

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/blueimp-file-upload/9.22.0/js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/blueimp-file-upload/9.22.0/js/jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/blueimp-file-upload/9.22.0/js/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/blueimp-file-upload/9.22.0/js/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>

{# 1. BUTTON TO TRIGGER THE ACTION #}
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary js-upload-photos">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud-upload"></span> Upload photos
</button>

{# 2. FILE INPUT TO BE USED BY THE PLUG-IN #}
<input id="fileupload" type="file" name="file" multiple
       style="display: none;"
       data-url="{% url 'upload' %}"
       data-form-data='{"csrfmiddlewaretoken": "{{ csrf_token }}"}'>

{# 3. TABLE TO DISPLAY THE UPLOADED PHOTOS #}
<table id="gallery" class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Photo</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {% for photo in photos %}
      <tr>
        <td><a href="{{ photo.file.url }}">{{ photo.file.name }}</a></td>
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>

<div class="modal fade" id="modal-progress" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Uploading...</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="progress">
          <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 0%;">0%</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

views.py

```
def upload(request):
photos_list = Images.objects.all()
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = ImagesForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
            
            if form.is_valid():
                photo = form.save()
                data = {'is_valid': True, 'name': photo.file.name, 'url': photo.file.url}
            else:
                data = {'is_valid': False}
            return JsonResponse(data)
        return render(request, 'rango/upload.html', {'photos': photos_list},)
```

The output that I get for the `/upload/` page is

[image: 1]

As you can see, only text is getting display for upload button and uploading progress bar and it's not actually working.

My guess here is that the jQuery libraries aren't getting included or/and JavaScript code isn't working. I am a backend engineer, so please excuse this might be silly question about frontend.

Shall be thankful if someone helps with code specificities.

Comment: Why are you including the same script twice?

Comment: I have changed the code in a few places.